# typo3 createAction of a backend extension does not persist data

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x

I'm in a migration process from typo3 6.2.31 to 7.6.23

I have the following function:

```
public function createAction(\TYPO3\Institutsvideoverwaltung\Domain\Model\Category $newCategory) {
    $contentCat = $this->request->getArgument('newCategory');
    if ($contentCat['isRoot'] == '1') {
        $this->categoryRepository->add($newCategory);
        $this->addFlashMessage($newCategory->getName(), 'Kategorie erfolgreich angelegt!', \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\AbstractMessage::OK);
    } else {
        if (!empty($_POST['tx_institutsvideoverwaltung_auditgarant_institutsvideoverwaltungvideoverwaltungbackend']['catAllocationUIDs'])) {
            $catAllocationUIDs = $this->request->getArgument('catAllocationUIDs');
            foreach ($catAllocationUIDs as $catAllocationUID) {
                $category = $this->categoryRepository->findByUid($catAllocationUID);
                $category->addChildCategory($newCategory);
                $this->categoryRepository->update($category);
            }
            $this->addFlashMessage($newCategory->getName(), 'Kategorie erfolgreich angelegt!', \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\AbstractMessage::OK);
        } else {
            $this->addFlashMessage('Das Objekt wurde nicht angelegt, da keine Zuordnung erfolgt ist. Wenn es sich um kein Wurzelelement handelt, nehmen Sie zumindest eine Zuordnung vor.', '', \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\AbstractMessage::ERROR);
        }
    }
    /*  }*/
    $this->redirect('list');
}
```

It says all works fine, but it does not persist data. What could be the problem?

When I add manually a record to databse it is not shown as well :(

Update Out Var_dump
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some TeamViewer investigations we found the problem located in the the Model and in the TCA.

The Model had the attribute `protected $uid = ''` . Of course the UID cannot be a string and should not be declared as this. However, the debug in the createAction said the object is a "persisted entity" and so the Persistence Manager thought there is nothing to do. After removing the $uid from the model and updating to TCA to become 7 LTS compatible, the problem was solved.

I guess its not a problem to declare the $uid as an integer in the model but as a string it was just too much for the system. Amazing that this worked in TYPO3 6 LTS...

Answer (score 2):

***edit:*** I retract all I said here. @paul-beck is right, redirecting after createAction does in fact persist the created objects. I'm sure it wasn't always like that and can't find in the documentation when this was introduced. I'll leave this answer here as reference.

The AbstractController taking over when your action returns takes care of persisting automatically. This happens after createActions and updateActions. But your redirection prevents that from happening. Just incorporate the persisting manually by invoking persistall before redirecting like so and you should be fine.

```
$this->persistenceManager->persistAll();
$this->redirect('list');
```

You'll need an instance of the PersistenceManager.

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\PersistenceManagerInterface
 * @inject
 */
protected $persistenceManager;
```

Comment: Weird. Could you insert a debug istead of the redirect and post the output, like so:     \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump( $category );

Comment: also tested it, Object is present. Added a screenshot above.

Comment: Could that be a problem with TCA?

Comment: @j4k3 calling redirect() will invoke to persist everything automatically I guess. There is no need of using the PersistenceManager when an action does redirect... you just have to do it if you return 'something' in your action.